# storing data in an array which is defined in the delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm reading file paths from a database & converting them to NSURLs before adding them to an array that's defined (& alloc'd/initialised) in my delegate. The problem is that the urlArray, which receives the urls, is not being populated correctly.

```
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "select coffeeID, coffeeName from coffee";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            coffeeObj.coffeeName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

            coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;

            NSString *path = coffeeObj.coffeeName;
            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundPath];
            [appDelegate.urlArray addObject:url];


            [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];
            [coffeeObj release];
        }
    }
}
```

I try to access urlArray to find that it's empty

```
SQLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

 NSURL *url0 = [appDelegate.urlArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

The urls are created correctly, it's just that they don't seem to add into the urlArray as expected. Any ideas? thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think you understand how a delegate is supposed to work. You are not supposed to directly call methods on properties of delegates, but send messages for them to do as they please. This may not be an issue here, but you are breaking the standard cocoa conventions.

Comment: ok, I've been following a [tutorial](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-selecting-data.html) which I found on Sqlite database implementation. That's where I discovered the code. Thanks for the tip

Comment: What is the soundpath and where do you define it? Is it possible that you wanted to create the NSUrl from path and not soundpath?

Answer (score 0):

Check appDelegate.url property, maybe is nil and you never initialize array

You have a memory leak, url is not realased.

Comment: No it's been initialised in the AppDelegate

Comment: how you initilaize array?

maby like this:

`coffeeArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

if yes, you should call retain on object, or use dot


make sure that your code is call after initialize array

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps check that urlArray is actually mutable (and not a plain NSArray). Also make sure that the delegate has been initialized *before* your code executes. If you check coffeeArray in the same place you look at urlArray, does that array contain the data you expect?

Edit: In your own answer to the topic, you are comparing initializing a local variable to initializing a temporary local one and assigning it to your property. Perhaps that was actually the difference (if maybe not as obvious as in your sample).

Answer (score 0):

i got this to work by adding a line of code - as per below. I copied a technique used in another part if the tutorial (mentioned above) & this did the trick

Initially I'd initialised the urlArray as normal:

```
NSMutableArray *urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

However when a temp array was used this fixed the problem - I'm not sure why :)

```
NSMutableArray *tempUrlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.urlArray = tempUrlArray;
```